# Prevent AutoCalculation in Columns when exporting data from table to excel sheet

Tags: jquery, html, excel

I have to Create a report.I have a column in my database table  which stores Some Mathematical Equation(like -1-100) ,While Exporting the data to excel sheet from my report table which contain data from database .That column in excel sheet is giving the value like (-101)(auto calculating the value ).I don't  want that to happen , i want the **Equation** to be exported to excel.
Below is my code for exporting table to excel.i need to prevent auto calculation in excel sheet.Please help.

```js
                var htmls = "";
                var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
                var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';
                var base64 = function (s) {
                    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
                };

                var format = function (s, c) {
                    return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                        return c[p];
                    })
                };

               
                htmls = $('#PrintDiv').prop('outerHTML');
                var ctx = {
                    worksheet: 'Worksheet',
                    table: htmls
                }


                 var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.download = "WorkReport" + new Date().toISOString().replace(/[\-\:\.]/g, "") + ".xls";
                link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
               link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound obvious, but have you tried disabling the automatic calculate?

Formula > Calculation Options > Manual.

Comment: I have to do it using jquery , my report exports from table and get downloaded directly